# Custom generic spring data repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Using spring data, I have two tables that shares the same structure.
The two tables are represented by two different entities, that inherit from the same class :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SuperEntity<T extends SuperEntity> {
// ...
}

@Table(name = "FOO")
@Entity
public class Foo extends SuperEntity<Foo> {
// ...
}

@Table(name = "BAR")
@Entity
public class Bar extends SuperEntity<Bar> {
// ...
}
```

I also have a generic repository, that I would like to use to factorize to requesting logic, and two sub-repository : one for each table.

```
public interface GenericEvtRepository <T extends SuperEntity<?>> extends JpaRepository<T, String> { }

public interface FooRepository extends GenericEvtRepository<Foo>  {}

public interface BarRepository extends GenericEvtRepository<Bar>  {}
```

I would like to add an actual query implementation to this repository (i.e. using EntityManager / Criteria).
Therefore I tried to adapt the custom repository strategy to my generic case

```
@Repository
public class GenericEvtRepositoryImpl<T extends SuperEntity<?>> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, String> implements GenericEvtRepository<T>  {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    // Some logic using entityManager
   public SuperEntity myCustomRequest() { /*...*/ }
}
```

However my application doesn't start, with the exception :

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property myCustomRequest found for type Foo!
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but Spring seems to think that myCustomRequest is an attribute from my entities, instead of a method.

I'm using spring-boot 1.5.6 and spring-data-jpa 1.11.6.

[Minimal reproductible exemple](https://github.com/ptitFicus/spring-data-jpa-generic-custom-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Luckily I was able to reproduce your issue,

How spring recommends custom repository implementation is specified [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) in spring docs.

So, you can do something like below,

```
public interface CustomEntityRepository<T extends SuperTag<?>>
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer>, CustomEntityRepository<Foo>
public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Bar, Integer>, CustomEntityRepository<Bar>
```

And define **common** implementation for `CustomEntityRepository<T extends SuperTag<?>>` as below,

```
@Repository
// NOTE: Implementation name must follow convension as InterfaceName + 'Impl'
public class CustomEntityRepositoryImpl<T extends SuperTag<?>>  implements 
CustomEntityRepository<T> {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager entityManager;

   // Generic custom implementation here
}
```

Spring automatically detects implementation of Custom Interface `CustomEntityRepository` based on implementation class naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however after modifying my code to fit yours doesn't solve my problem. Would you have a working exemple ?

Comment: you can refer this https://github.com/iamitpatil1993/spring-data-jpa/commit/e0498e4183d070aa37875d7b11e6aa7d2c235718 Names are quite different,  hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, however I think that my issue is that I don't use the same version of spring-data-jpa. Here is a minial exemple : https://github.com/ptitFicus/spring-data-jpa-generic-custom-repository

Comment: As I noticed this problem occurs only when repo is generic.. Did you solve this problem?